# Public engagement – why, when and how?

Tags: cv, outreach

I believe in public engagement and personally, I think all PhD students should engage in some form of public engagement. During my PhD, I’ve done activities at primary schools and participate in a few public engagement events in the UK. Now, I have another job, in another field (PhD in allergic diseases and current job is cancer-related), so to do public engagement and attend any scientific conference related to allergic diseases, I have to take days off work.

This year, I have the opportunity to present the work I’ve done during my PhD at one large conference for non-scientists. I was wondering how public engagement is seen by other scientists. The benefits of doing public engagement are not as evident for the presenter as attending a scientific conference as there are more opportunities for collaboration in a scientific conference.

I’m mostly wondering how public engagement is seen by other scientists (related or unrelated fields). Do you think it’s an advantage to have public engagement activities in the CV, presenting your work for non-scientists, or do you think it’s better to have a Twitter account, a blog or write short articles for non-scientists?

Comment: I would suggest raising this question in chat. It’s iffy because you’re requesting an evaluation of a specific conference, which is something we don’t like to do here.

Comment: Thank you! I actually don't know how to do that. Do I need to create a room chat? Could you help me or point me to an explanation?

Comment: There’s a link to the main room chat in the drop-down menu at the top right.

Comment: I will actually edit the question to make it more general and applicable to every field.

Comment: Related questions: [How can a researcher improve his contribution to society?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/4738/546) and [Why are contributions to the education of the broader public not valued much within academia?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38405/546)

Comment: Interesting questions @scaaahu. Thank you for those! I see that, at least on Academia, people are interested and see value in public engagement, which is great. I know there are a lot of blogs out there and I've certainly considered that several times. But should one only blog/present or should engage in all different methods available? Blog, social media, activities, presentations?